# How to report results for generalised linear mixed model (glmmTMB) with beta distribution and logit link?

Tags: r, logistic, glmm, beta-distribution, reporting

I am currently analysing the effect of canopy cover on the proportion of birds scavenging on carrion left out in nature. The data comes from several national parks, which I included as a random factor. I'm using a GLMM with beta distribution and logit link. My summary output is listed below. I'm doubting which values I should report when stating that the proportion decreases significantly with canopy cover. Of course I could use the P-value and perhaps the number of data points on which it is based (P < 0.001, n = 34). Publications with similar analyses report F statistics or R-squared. I read somewhere that the ICC (random effect variance vs overall variance) is a good statistic to report. Does somebody know what is accepted to report with GLMM with beta distribution and logit link, and how to get these statistics?

```r
Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover + (1 | Area)
Data: df_prop_birds_eating
Weights: pointWeight_scaled

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    -5.3      0.8      6.7    -13.3       30 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Area   (Intercept) 1.198e-10 1.094e-05
Number of obs: 34, groups:  Area, 6

Overdispersion parameter for beta family (): 5.17 

Conditional model:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     1.7869     0.7196   2.483 0.013017 *  
OverheadCover  -4.7387     1.2661  -3.743 0.000182 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```